# Meaning of 意義があるかどうかは自分で判断しないかもしれません

Tags: meaning

I understand what 判断する means e.g.

彼は人を見た目で判断しない - He does not judge people by appearances.

However, I'm failing to understand what is being meant by 自分で判断しないかもしれません in the last part of this exchange.

自分で判断しない from my understanding means something like "to not decide by oneself". However I think I am missing something to help me understand what she is trying to say.

A little bit of extra context:

- 神奈様 is actually a God who wants to live as a human (and currently is) for reasons currently unknown to the reader.
- Person 1 is the new 巫女 at the 神社 who realises that is it 'empty'
- Person 2, not much is known about them.

> Person 2「神奈様は人として生きたがっています」
>
> Person 1 「それは私も伺いました」
>
> Person 2「それっていけないことなんですか？」
>
> Person 1 「そう願うことは悪いことではないでしょう。ですが、そこには神奈さんが神であるという厳然たる事実が立ち塞がります」
>
> Person 2「『生まれ』からは逃れられないということですか」
>
> Person 1 「あなたは、神奈さんに逃げてほしいと思いますか？」
>
> Person 2「っ……それは……」
>
> Person 1 「本当に考えなければならないことというのは、時に心を苛みます」
>
> Person 1 「ですから、味方が必要なのです。でも、耳に心地よいことばかり言う者が味方とは限りません」
>
> Person 1「対決しなければならない敵は自分――自らをそこに追いこむことはなかなか難しいことです」
>
> Person 2 「あなたはいやがられても、神奈様のためになることをするというのですか？」
>
> Person 1 「必要とあらば。でも、それに**意義があるかどうかは自分で判断しないかもしれません**」
>
> Person 2「…………よく、わかりません。言ってることが難しいです……」

Comment: Your understanding seems fine. It's not clear what your problem is. Maybe it will become apparent if you try to translate the whole of the sentence.

Comment: If I was to be very literal: If it is necessary. However, as for whether there would be meaning in that, not decide by oneself （かもしれません）. I'm not sure how I would translate かもしれません based on the rest of the translation which makes me think I am misunderstanding what the sentence says

Comment: I don't know without more context, but is there anything wrong with "I might not judge by myself whether or not ..."?

Comment: I guess what trips me up in my mind is that it looks like she is saying she might not judge by herself, however this is a very ??? statement to me.  Now if she was saying she is "unable" to do it by herself then that might make sense to me, however from my understanding that doesn't appear to be what she is saying, thus my confusion (and why I think I am misunderstanding)

Comment: @orestes32 What kind of person is Person 1 and what is their relationship with 神奈様? Also, if there are any special circumstances in the story surrounding these two characters (and potentially other characters related to Person 1), you should add them as context to the question. Also, you might want to double-check that the text matches the source, i.e. that there are no typos.

Comment: Also, a few preceding/following sentences could be useful, too.

Comment: Added a bit more

Comment: I think she's saying that she herself won't make that judgement, but instead Kanasama(sp?) will decide what significance Person 1's action will have. Or if not Kanasama, then some outside party/force might made the decision for her.

Comment: @Fireheart251 Yeah, most likely she means that she relies on something else to make that decision/judgement. In some cases you could reword it as「それに意義があるかどうかを判断するのは、（私自身ではなく、）○○かもしれません。」. This wouldn't make sense in all conceivable scenarios though, and it doesn't seem possible to draw any conclusions with the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I somewhat sympathize with Person 2 here (the line *is* pretty cryptic), language-wise, what Person 1 is saying is relatively straightforward. Taken at face value, what she says is that she might not make an attempt to determine whether her course of action has meaning or not, i.e. something along the lines of “However, I might not (try to) determine/judge/decide whether there is meaning to that or not”.

Since she explicitly says「自分で」, it may be that she relies on something else (the traditional teachings of her religion, the opinion of her peers, the voice of a higher entity etc) to guide her, and she might not make any attempts to question this source of guidance of her own volition. The source of guidance could also simply be a deep-rooted cognitive habit (a 'personality trait'), i.e. this course of action might be her default choice for no identifiable reason, and she might never have thought to doubt its validity. Another possibility is that she actually lacks the ability to make such decisions for some as-of-yet unknown reason.

Here,「かもしれない」is used in its usual sense ("maybe", "perhaps", "I guess", "it is possible that"...), i.e. it introduces an element of uncertainty. This could literally mean that she isn't sure of whether her statement is true or not, or she might be using it out of reluctance to accept her own statement, or she might be using it to deliberately confuse Person 2 / to keep them in the dark, etc.

Either way, this is about as much as you can infer at this point.